# Typescript - nested map type gives confusing type hints

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've written a nested `Omit` type in two different ways, but the one that makes more sense to me gives convoluted type hints while the one that's less intuitive actually looks best. Here goes:

```js
type HasSameNested = {
    a: {
        c: number; d: string
    },
    b: {
        c: string; d: number
    }
}; // flipped C and D types

type Omit2<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1]> = {
    [P1 in keyof T]: P1 extends K1 ? {
        [P2 in Exclude<keyof T[K1], K2>]: T[P1][P2]
    } : T[P1]
}

type Omit2_2<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1]> = {
    [P1 in keyof T]: P1 extends K1 ? {
        [P2 in Exclude<keyof T[P1], K2>]: T[P1][P2]
    } : T[P1]
}

type omit_union = Omit2<HasSameNested, 'a' | 'b', 'c'>;
let T6: omit_union;
T6.a; // works, type is { d: string }
T6.b; // works, type is { d: number }

type omit_union_2 = Omit2_2<HasSameNested, 'a' | 'b', 'c'>;
let T7: omit_union_2;
T7.a.d = 'a'; // works but types are ugly:
// a: { [P2 in Exclude<keyof HasSameNested[K1 & "a"], "c">]: HasSameNested[K1 & "a"][P2]; }
// d: d: HasSameNested[K1 & "a"]["d"]

T7.b.d = 4; // works but types are ugly, as above
```

Assigning the wrong type to `T7.b.d` or `T7.a.d` does tell me e.g. `string is not assignable to number`, but **I don't understand** why using `Exclude<keyof T[P1], K2>` gives such convoluted typing even though `P1 in keyof T` and `P1 extends K1`, and `Exclude<keyof T[K1], K2>` gives the correct types.

Comment: It does seem like the quickinfo/IntelliSense for `Omit2_2` is weird... the seemingly unbound type parameter `K1` is present, which is surprising.  Maybe that part is a bug in Intellisense?

Comment: The fact that an intersection shows up where you never used one in your definition is due to a [change in TS3.4](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29437) whereby `T extends U ? F<T> : V` is simplified to `F<T & U>` if `T` definitely extends `U`.  The part where the type parameter makes it into IntelliSense is unexpected, though.

Comment: Shorter repro: `type Hmm<T extends U, U> = T extends U ? { [K in keyof T]: any } : never; type What = Hmm<{ a: string }, {}>`

Comment: The intersection type shows up because `P1` extends `K1`? I've read the change but don't grasp the rationale - isn't `P1` already specific enough? What extra information is conveyed by `P1 & K1` as a type?

Comment: Yeah [me too](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29437#issuecomment-475471829)... I guess optional properties do add info

Comment: That's interesting, I'll try and come up with an example using optional properties there these two implementations differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the compiler to me.  I've just filed [Microsoft/TypeScript#31326](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31326) and will report back with updated information from there.  Good luck!

UPDATE, 2019-05-10:  This has been marked as bug by one of the language designers.  Not sure when it will be fixed, but at least we know you're right to be confused about that type information.

UPDATE, 2019-05-11: As you noticed, this bug is now [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31337) and has been merged into `master`.  That means if you now try your code with `typescript@next` you should see the new behavior:

```
type omit_union_2 = Omit2_2<HasSameNested, 'a' | 'b', 'c'>;
declare let T7: omit_union_2;
T7.a; // works, type is { d: string }
T7.b; // works, type is { d: number }
```

I don't see a difference between your `T6` and `T7` types anymore.  So, looks like this was entirely caused by that compiler bug, and should go away when TypeScript 3.5 is released on or around May 30, 2019.

Okay, good luck to you!

Comment: This is exciting! Thanks for posting the bug report. Are you sure our examples relate to the same thing? I ask because in my example I could assign the correct types to e.g. `T7.a.d`, it's just that the type information isn't very clear. In your example it seems like the type is inferred incorrectly altogether.

Comment: I was a little surprised that the issue was actually affecting the type system and not just IntelliSense.  The fact that an intersection of a runaway type parameter survived into the final type is either your whole problem or a big problem that's hiding other issues you're having.  Either way I think it needs to be fixed in the compiler before I could feel confident about any further advice here.

Comment: Yes, and pushed to the master branch, so we can test it.  Updated the answer with the results (spoiler: looks good now!)